# backstack require two clicks to make action with fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, fragment-backstack

I'm using activity had many fragments first it contains Fragment A which has a list opens Fragment B which has a list opens fragment C which has a list open Another activity I handle back stack clicks when user in the main activity but when the other activity opens and go back to the first one the back click didn't make action until you click on it in twice.

here is the code of opening the fragment

```
protected void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        String TAG = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_home, fragment, TAG);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(TAG);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

and here is the code of backstack action

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: You have many fragments and want to handle backstack this is my understanding.And if yes second question is do you have single activity or have more then one?

Comment: I already handled the backstack and it works fine when I was in the activity which had the multiple fragment but when I go back from other activity there was a problem it requires two clicks on the back button to make an action